# EF Core 7 - .ToJson() and HasConversion : when to use what and how to use properly?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Beating my head against a wall to try to get a column to just look like a normal piece of JSON.

The object(s) I am trying to work with:

the database DTO

```
public class GoesToDb:
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<MatchSuccess> MatchSuccesses { get; set; } = new List<MatchSuccess>();
    public List<MatchFailure> MatchFailures { get; set; } = new List<MatchFailure>();
}

public class MatchSuccess
{
    public MatchSuccess()
    {
        Meta = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
   
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Meta { get; set; }
}

public class MatchFailure
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I am struggling to get the `MatchSuccess` to just store as a basic JSON() string block.

`MatchFailures` of course is simple. The issue is the `Meta` dictionary.

I read that the `.ToJson()` just needs to be applied at the root, but then the `Meta` says it needs to be included. What I have sort of works, but it looks like hell in the db and you can't just parse it back out.

The `MatchSuccesses` column should look like this in the DB

```
"MatchSuccesses": [
    {
        "Foo": "888",
        "Bar": "236129",
        "Meta": {
            "Item1": "236129"
        }
    }
]
```

but instead I keep getting this:

```
[{"Meta":"{\u0022Item1\u0022:\u0022236129\u0022}","Foo":"236129","Bar":"888"}]
```

and I can't just parse that back easily. It works.... it looks absolutely horrendous.

My `ContextBuilder` looks like the following. I cannot understand how to get the `Meta` portion to be treated as part of the `MatchSuccess` object correctly. `HasOne`, `OwnsOne`, Property.. I am glazing over with this...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GoesToDb>(entity =>
        {
            entity.OwnsMany(e => e.MatchSuccesses, builder =>
            {
                builder.ToJson();
                builder.Property(p => p.Meta)
                    .HasConversion(
                        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, options),
                        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(v, options));
            
            });
            entity.OwnsMany(e => e.MatchFailures, b =>
            {
                b.ToJson();
            });
```

Thank you for any advice on what is likely 30 seconds for someone who deals with Entity Framework Core on a daily basis. This thing is giving me a rash.

Comment: If I do
```builder.OwnsOne(c => c.Meta).ToJson();```

my result is empty Meta

```
 [{"Bar":"236129","Foo":"888","Meta":{}}]
```
Same result with : 
``` 
builder.OwnsOne<Dictionary<string,string>>(c => c.Meta).ToJson();

result
[{"Bar":"236129","Foo":"888","Meta":{}}] 
```